# ZuulException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I use Zuul to build ApiGateway,But sometimes use will accept 404 . a very small probability.
I didn't use eureka and Ribbon.The Zuul route rule from mysql .

The exception stack:

```
2018-05-04 11:18:13,354 | ERROR | com.wlqq.etc.gkgateway.filter.CustomRoutingFilter.run(43) | --> ERROR In Forward:{}
org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.util.ZuulRuntimeException: com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:200)
    at com.wlqq.etc.gkgateway.filter.CustomRoutingFilter.run(CustomRoutingFilter.java:34)
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118)
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96)
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116)
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:157)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.util.ZuulRuntimeException.<init>(ZuulRuntimeException.java:33)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:282)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forwardRequest(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:385)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forward(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:304)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:195)
    ... 74 more
```

2018-05-04 11:18:13,371 | ERROR | com.wlqq.etc.gkgateway.filter.CustomRoutingFilter.run(48) | --> ERROR In forward model etc-invoice-channel :http://example.com/xx/apply-send, param:null

Comment: It's literally there. Line 34 of CustomRoutingFilter.java. Work backwards.

Comment: Looks like more of a networking error. Can you check your `CustomRouting` on the said line #? I'm editing your question so that your internal URL is not exposed in question.